# Image Thumbnails & Downloading Them

Tags: php, html

I have the following code for creating thumbnails of the images in the database automatically when the are uploaded.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos where caption='cars'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<div id="imagelist">';
    echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Now whenever I click an image in the gallery I want it to open the image in a new tab and give me an option to download, I want the download code which will take in the photo id from the database and then give me the option to download that image only how to do it.

Comment: If it is jpg files then you can follow 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562523/creating-a-download-link-for-jpg-file-using-php

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, please read the documentation and use either pdo or mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    $file    = your file
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

mysql_* functions are deprecated in new version of php, So use mysqli_* functions OR PDO

Comment: +1 little suggestion to use pdo or mysqli would make answer more useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 :)

Comment: @user2218550 : It is name of the file.

Comment: @user2218550 : Ref the examples given in http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php , You will get better idea.